# DIVs are collapsing with position set "relative"

Tags: css, css-float, position, image-resizing

I've got a website that has a big image covering the screen. In its image there are several DIVs (Text, Forms, Images) (see picture 2). The big image container is made displaying always the center of the image regardless of window size, so when you make your windows smaller, the very center stays visible.

The problem now is that the DIVs are collapsing, when I scale down the window size (see picture 3).

Picture number 2 depicts what it is intended to be look like!

```
#div1 {
  width:25%;
  left: 32%;
  top:7.5%;
  position: relative;
  float:left;   
  }

#div2 {
  position:relative;
  left:37.5%;
  clear:both;
  width:14%;
  height:20%;
  }


    #div2 h2 {
      width:10%;
      left:15%;
      margin-top:11%;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      }

#div3 {
  left: 64.4%;
  top:-2.5%;
  width:111px;
  position: relative;
  }


#div4{
  left: 93%;
  top:-18.0%;
  width:111px;
  position: relative;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper"\>

        <div id="div1">
            <h1>Seite nicht gefunden!</h1>
        </div>

        <h2>Bug melden</h2>

        <div id="div2">


            <form>
                  <label>Titel</label>
                  <input type="text" id="form_title" name="title" placeholder="Ich will einen Bug melden!" required>

                  <label>URL</label>
                  <input type="url" id="form_url" name="URL" placeholder="###" >

                  <label>Beschreibung</label>
                  <textarea type="text" id="form_whathappened" name="happened" placeholder="Was ist passiert?" required></textarea>

                  <input type="submit" value="Absenden" /> 
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="div3">
            <a href="http://www.###.de" target="new"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
        </div>

        <div id="div4">
            <a href="http://www.###.de" target="new"><p>Jetzt<br/ >Tester<br />werden!<br /></p></a>
        </div>



    </div>



</body>
```

Can you please help me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

Christoph

[image: Full window size]

[image: That's how it should look like after resizing the window]

[image: That's what it looks like instead]

Comment: Hey, can you show us your HTML code?

Comment: Of course! I updated it. Thanks!

Comment: I've spotted a spelling mistake `<div id="wrapper"\>` should be `<div id="wrapper">`. Put the `<h2>` tag inside the `<div id="div2">` this will keep it in place. P.S. Do you have any css rule for the **#wrapper**? Because this could play you bad later on. I would probably set **width** and **margin** to "wrap" the page, just to make sure everything will be on place.

Comment: could you please have a look: http://test.textzess.de/.

At the moment it just works on Chrome :-/

Answer (score 1):

This is probably way far from perfect, but it's worth trying.

The html code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>404</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="error">
                <h1>Seite nicht gefunden!</h1>
            </div>
            <form id="form">
                        <h2>Bug melden</h2>
                        <label>Titel</label>
                        <input type="text" id="form_title" name="title" placeholder="Ich will einen Bug melden!" required>

                        <label>URL</label>
                        <input type="url" id="form_url" name="URL" placeholder="http://www.###/???" >

                        <label>Beschreibung</label>
                        <textarea type="text" id="form_whathappened" name="happened" placeholder="Was ist passiert?" required></textarea>

                        <input type="submit" value="Absenden" /> 
            </form>
 ... //other code goes here</div>
```

and this is the edited section of the css code:

```
#wrapper { width: 640px; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; }
#error { font-size: 120%; margin: 65px 0 0 60px; float:left; }
#error h1 { font-size: 150%; text-align:center; }
#form { margin: 15px 86px; width:260px; height: 40%; float: left; background: green; }
```

Check the working example here: [example](http://bborisov.me/dev/test/)

Hope that helps as a start.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. 

Unfortunately, I don't get the solution for a wrapper that is NOT aligned central. What if the wrapper is as big as the background image? How can I tell the text to be aligned with a special part of the background image no matter what screen size?

Comment: The `wrapper` has set `width` and `margin:auto`, therefore it will be always centred according to the `width` of the screen: f.e. if the resolution is 1600px and the `wrapper` has a `widht` of 940px the leftover of 660px will be equally distributed to centre the `wrapper`. Align the text with a certain part is tricky. What I usually do is to set that background image(or parts of it) to a smaller `div` that I can easily control.